# Dynamically expanfing loop top border

Tags: kotlin

I faced the following problem. Here's my method which replaces all vertical lines in string from abs value to Math.abs (like |7| -> to Math.abs(7)):

```
private fun replaceAbs(_expression: String): String {
    var expression = _expression
    var isOpenAbsBracket = true

    for (i in 0 until expression.length) {
        if (expression[i] == '|') {
            expression = if (isOpenAbsBracket) {
                isOpenAbsBracket = false
                "${expression.substring(
                    0,
                    i
                )}Math.abs(${expression.substring(i + 1)}"
            } else {
                isOpenAbsBracket = true
                "${expression.substring(
                    0,
                    i
                )})${expression.substring(i + 1)}"
            }
        }

    }

    return expression
}
```

I need to execute it as many times as the new `expression` string length is. But when I run the app passing param "|7|" loop is executed only 3 times. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: When the for-loop is entered initially, the "until" operator creates a range object which doesn't adapt its end later when the "expression.length" changes. Try a while-loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Butscher says, the loop condition of a `for ()` loop is evaluated once at the start, and not each time through the loop.  So in your example, the string starts off with 3 chars, so that's what it loops over.

This is discussed on the Kotlin discussion board [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/for-loop-with-dynamic-condition/57).

An immediate fix might be to use a `while ()` loop, which *does* evaluate the condition each time through.

However, that would still be pretty inefficient.  In general, it's a bad idea to manipulate strings in a loop: here, each time through, it creates two new String objects for the substrings, a StringBuilder to collect everything, and then another String for the result.  That's likely to be a problem if your strings get very long, and/or you're doing thousands of them per second.

In general, the answer to string manipulation is to use a StringBuilder explicitly, and to keep the data there as long as possible before converting it back to a String (if at all).  So you could create a StringBuilder, initialise it to the string parameter, and loop over that (with a `while ()` loop).  You could use `replace()` or `insert()` to make the changes.  But that's still inefficient, as it has to move the remainder of the string up each time.

So a better solution would be to loop over the chars of the original string *copying* them to a StringBuilder.  Here's how I might write it:

```
private fun String.replaceAbs()
    = buildString {
        var inAbsBracket = false
        for (c in this@replaceAbs) {
            if (c == '|') {
                inAbsBracket = !inAbsBracket
                append(if (inAbsBracket) "Math.abs(" else ")")
            } else
                append(c)
        }
    }
```

Instead of taking a parameter, I've made it an extension function (`String.replaceAbs()`), so you can call it like this: `"|7|".replaceAbs()`.  (Of course, it could work as a normal function too, but I find this sort of extension function reads well.)

This uses a `StringBuilder`, but instead of creating it explicitly, this uses the standard library's [`buildString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html) function, which creates one for you, lets you access it as `this` inside the lambda, and then converts it to a String afterward.  And because all the function body is inside the lambda, it's slightly more concise to give the function an expression body (`=` instead of `{`…`}`).

I've flipped the condition, calling it `inAbsBracket`, so it starts off false, and gets set to true while we're inside the bracket; this seems marginally easier to follow.

It loops over every char in the original string.  (Here you have to call it `this@replaceAbs`, because `this` refers to the StringBuilder inside the `buildString()` lambda.)  You don't need to know the indices when doing it this way, so it's simpler to loop over the characters directly.

Then it appends either `Math.abs(` or `)` in place of a `|`, *or else* the character from the original string; it needs to do the latter as it's creating a copy of the original string, not manipulating it in place.  (Because `this` is the StringBuilder inside the lambda, it can just call `append()` directly.)

This is about as efficient as you can get; it does a single scan over the string, and creates only one StringBuilder and one String for the result.  Hopefully, it's also relatively easy to read — at least, once you're used to some of Kotlin's cool features!

Comment: The best answer I have ever got here, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii My pleasure! Almost any non-trivial bit of code can be improved (including the code I wrote above, no doubt!), and it's a great exercise to puzzle out how to make something simpler, shorter, easier to read, more efficient, more robust, easier to use, and/or more general. Sometimes those things conflict, so you have to balance them; but it's great when they work together. (And some things are a matter of taste, of course.) If I've given you some ideas, then you're very welcome!